# How to raise and lower items in a QGraphicsScene?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I want to lower and raise an item in a QGraphicsScene.
I have played around with zValue but that does not make very sense to me because of the fact that I have to set the zValue for each item in the scene prior to set the zValue of the selected item. 
The zValues are all set to ZERO after adding them to the scene. So there must be an ordered list which will be used for rendering.
Is there a possibillity to just change this order?
I allready tried `scene->items().move()` which does not work for me.

Comment: Are you looking for https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#stackBefore ? Or perhaps I misunderstood the question. See also https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#sorting

Comment: I think thats it. Thx

Comment: Now I was able to code the raise and lower methods.
But one question is left.
How do I repaint the item after changing its position?
item->update(); does not work...
item->setSelected(false); item->setSelected(true); does work, but...